# Applescript — How can I address empty spaces on a folder path?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript

I am having trouble executing an AppleScript using a folder path that contains empty spaces. How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myWin to window 1
    set thePath to (quoted form of POSIX path of (target of myWin as alias))
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        tell window 1
            do script "/Users/johndoe/Company Dropbox/John Doe/Folder " & thePath
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: You can use `quoted form of` the string, otherwise you will need to escape characters special to the shell.

Comment: How can I use `quoted form of`?

Comment: something like `do script quoted form of ("/Users/johndoe/Company Dropbox/John Doe/Folder " & thePath)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@red_menace solution works; However I found another option. You can add `\\` to address empty spaces on a folder path.

**Example:**

```
"/Users/johndoe/Company\\ Dropbox/John\\ Doe/Folder"
                       ^^             ^^
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this doesn't work for a Folder name such as "Company - Dropbox" (with a hyphen in between)?